# More chapters requested. Is this a good sign?

Tags: publishing

I sent out the first four chapters to about six different publishers. Within three days I received a no from one. On the ninth day, I got a request for additional chapters from another publisher. Is that a good sign? They didn't ask from the entire manuscript which concerned me but the first chapters had to spark an interest if they asked for more right? I'm so nervous!

Comment: The ambiguity of the question aside, of course it is a good sign. Send them more chapters.

Comment: The answer is yes, but depending on your genre it can pay to approach agents instead of publishers. I'm guessing your writing is in non-fiction, where that's often not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

I'd consider it a good sign.

After one publisher said, "no," someone else apparently found your work more interesting. So they answered "maybe," instead of "no," and asked for more chapters to help make a decision.

Comment: Note that the publisher that requested additional chapters was not the same publisher that responded with a rejection. OP has clarified this in the question; you may want to revise or even delete your answer in response.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: OK, fixed. Thanks for your help.